# Dask seems to be sharing memory for global variable, which I thought was impossible

Tags: python, dask

Here are some reproducible codes:

1. Here is Dask with global variable:

```
# method_file.py

import dask
import random

class TestClass():

    def from_dataframe(self, pdf):
        global data
        data = pdf

    @staticmethod
    def work(elem):
        data.iloc[0, 0] = 9999
        return len(data) + elem

    def do(self):
        tasks = [dask.delayed(TestClass.work)(random.randint(1,500)) for x in range(10)]
        re = dask.compute(*tasks)
        return re
```

```
# main_file.py

from method_file import TestClass
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ar = np.arange(500000000).reshape(5000000, 100)
    pdf = pd.DataFrame(ar)

    tc = TestClass()
    tc.from_dataframe(pdf)
    print(tc.do())
    print(pdf.head(3))
```

```
python3 main_file.py
```

This outputs:

```
(5000117, 5000054, 5000304, 5000111, 5000010, 5000264, 5000201, 5000346, 5000486, 5000376)
     0    1    2    3    4    5    6   ...   93   94   95   96   97   98   99
0  9999    1    2    3    4    5    6  ...   93   94   95   96   97   98   99
1   100  101  102  103  104  105  106  ...  193  194  195  196  197  198  199
2   200  201  202  203  204  205  206  ...  293  294  295  296  297  298  299

[3 rows x 100 columns]
```

This means the `work` method was able to read `data` global variable. Not only that, it even mutated the `pdf` variable! I know that multiprocessing with `fork` can read data this way as well, as we can see below.

2. Here is multiprocessing with `fork` start method.

```
# method_file2.py

from multiprocessing import Pool
import multiprocessing
import random

class TestClass():

    def from_dataframe(self, pdf):
        global data
        data = pdf

    @staticmethod
    def work(elem):
        data.iloc[0, 0] = 9999
        return len(data) + elem

    def do(self):

        multiprocessing.set_start_method('fork')

        pool = Pool(6)
        procs = [pool.apply_async(TestClass.work, args=(random.randint(1,500), )) for i in range(1, 10)]
        re = [proc.get() for proc in procs]
        return re
```

```
# main_file2.py

from method_file2 import TestClass
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ar = np.arange(500000000).reshape(5000000, 100)
    pdf = pd.DataFrame(ar)

    tc = TestClass()
    tc.from_dataframe(pdf)
    print(tc.do())
    print(pdf.head(3))
```

```
python3 main_file2.py
```

This outputs:

```
[5000456, 5000346, 5000122, 5000120, 5000358, 5000067, 5000375, 5000444, 5000288]
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6   ...   93   94   95   96   97   98   99
0    0    1    2    3    4    5    6  ...   93   94   95   96   97   98   99
1  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  ...  193  194  195  196  197  198  199
2  200  201  202  203  204  205  206  ...  293  294  295  296  297  298  299

[3 rows x 100 columns]
```

As you can see, it can read since the state of the main process is copied, but it cannot mutate the object (`pdf`).

I won't include any more codes here for brevity, but I also tried timing cloudpickling the `pdf` object, and I know for fact that Dask is not pickling that data frame. How is it possible that Dask can share memory across process this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see you setting up any processes. Dask's default scheduler uses a thread pool, so all tasks are able to see the same variables. See https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/scheduler-overview.html